# Improper integral related proof

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, limsup-and-liminf

Let $ f:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R} $ be an increasing nonnegative function such that $ \intop_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx $ converges.

What I need to prove is that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=\intop_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx $.

And in order to do it, I should follow the guidance in the question.

These are the steps:

Step one:

I proved that for any $ 2\leq n\in\mathbb{N} $ it follows that

$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\leq\intop_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx $

This wasn't hard. I fixed $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ and set a partition of the segment $ \left[0,\frac{n-1}{n}\right] $.
The expression in the left side is a lower Darboux sum, so it's smaller then the integral from $ 0 $ to $\frac{n-1}{n} $ and because $ f $ is nonnegative and increasing, it is also smaller than the integral.

Now, I'm stuck on the second step:

Fix $ 0<\delta<1 $.

Prove that $ \liminf\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)\geq\intop_{0}^{1-\delta}f\left(x\right)dx $.

I'm not sure how to do it, any idea would be helpful.

The last step is simply to conclude that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=\intop_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx $

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given that $f$ is increasing and **non-zero**.  I also assume $f(0)$ is finite and the improper nature of the integral (if any) is due to behavior near $x = 1$. In the first part of the argument you are using

$$\int_0^{1-1/n} f(x) \, dx \leqslant \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx,$$

which is not necessarily true, since it is not given that $f$ is nonnegative. We could add a constant $C$ so that $C+f(x) > 0$ and proceed to prove that $C $ plus the limit of the sum equals $C$ plus the integral. However, there is a straightforward proof, as follows, which also handles the lower bound.

Since $f$ is increasing on $[0,1)$ we have

$$\frac{1}{n} f\left(\frac{k}{n} \right) \leqslant \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} f(x) \, dx \leqslant \frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{k+1}{n} \right)$$

Summing from $k = 0$ to $k = n-2$, we get

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\left(\frac{k}{n} \right) \leqslant \int_0^{1-1/n} f(x) \, dx \leqslant \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\left(\frac{k+1}{n} \right) \\ = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\left(\frac{k}{n} \right) - \frac{1}{n}f(0) + \frac{1}{n}f(1-1/n)$$

Rearranging, we get

$$\int_0^{1-1/n} f(x) \, dx + \frac{1}{n}f(0) -  \frac{1}{n}f(1-1/n)\leqslant \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\left(\frac{k}{n} \right) \leqslant \int_0^{1-1/n} f(x) \, dx $$

Clearly, $\underset{n \to \infty}\lim \frac{1}{n} f(0) = 0$, and since the integral over $[0,1)$ converges, we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^{1-1/n} f(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$$

If we can show that $\underset{n \to \infty}\lim \frac{1}{n} f(1- 1/n) = 0$, then by the squeeze theorem it follows that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\left(\frac{k}{n} \right) = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$$

**Proof that $\underset{n \to \infty}\lim \frac{1}{n} f(1- 1/n) = 0$**.

Since $f$ is increasing we have,

$$\tag{*}\frac{1}{2n} f(1- 1/n)\leqslant \int_{1 - 1/n}^{1- 1/(2n)} f(x) \, dx $$

Since the integral converges, it follows by the Cauchy criterion that for any $\epsilon > 0$ the RHS is smaller that $\epsilon/2$ for all sufficiently large $n$. This implies that $\frac{1}{n} f(1- 1/n)< \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and $\underset{n \to \infty}\lim \frac{1}{n} f(1- 1/n) = 0$.

Comment: I’m sorry. Indeed, $ f $ is non-negative. As for the rest, great, you proved the final conclusion directly, so I can basically conclude the second step from your proof. 

Is there another way to prove directly the second step and conclude the final step as whoever wrote this question wanted us to solve ?

Comment: Sure — you have it here when $f$ is nonnegative using the left inequality. Take $n$ so large that $1 -\delta$ is less than $1-1/n$ and the extra terms on the left are negligible. Then liminf of the sum is bigger than the integral over $[0,1-\delta]$. It’s kind of a clumsy way to do this.